# Applying class calendar via different method

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to create [calendar](https://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-calendarview-example.html) in one of my fragments, yet I can't figure out how can I call the calendar class into the onCreate(); function in fragmentTwo.java.
I have tried this, but I keep getting error:

> FATAL ERROR Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference

.

fragmentTwo.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
}
```

Calendar.java:

```
public class Calendar extends AppCompatActivity {

    CalendarView calendarView;
    TextView dateDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);

        calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        dateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_display);
        dateDisplay.setText("Date: ");

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                dateDisplay.setText("Date: " + i2 + " / " + i1 + " / " + i);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Date:\n" + "Day = " + i2 + "\n" + "Month = " + i1 + "\n" + "Year = " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I apply the Calendar class in my fragmentTwo `onCreate()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onCreate()` method in a Fragment is called after the Activity's onAttachFragment() but before that Fragment's `onCreateView()`.

So basically you can't do view stuff inside onCreate() .

So you need to add those two lines

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
```

in `onCreateView()`

Link to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. can you please direct me to link that explains when to use onCreateView?

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem :) . I update the answer with docs link